# Does window and slide intervals affect the spark streaming application performance

Tags: apache-spark, dataset, spark-streaming, rdd

As far as I understand data size will vary as per window interval and slide interval and big intervals like weekly and more (though monthly interval is not allowed) might affect performance as actual data would be stored in rdds in a datastream.

Does window and slide intervals affect the spark streaming application performance? if yes, then what are ways to fine tune performance and intervals?